# Rails link which POSTs in development GETs in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, I have a `JobsController`, which has the following `delete` action:

```
def delete
  @body_id = "body_jobs"
  @job = Job.find(params[:id])
  render :layout => false if request.xhr?
  return unless request.post?
  if @job.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Job successfully deleted"
    redirect_to clients_url(:action => :index, :id => @job.client)
  end
end
```

With the following view (the relevant part, at least):

```
<ul class="actions">
  <li><%= link_to(image_tag("/images/button_yes.png", :alt => "Yes"), jobs_url(:action => :delete, :id => @job), :method => :post) %></li>
  <li><%= link_to(image_tag("/images/button_no.png", :alt => "No"), jobs_url(:action => :view, :id => @job), :class => "close" ) %></li>
</ul>
```

The generated html in development is:

```
<ul class="actions">
    <li><a rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="http://localhost:3000/jobs/delete/10"><img alt="Yes" src="/images/button_yes.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a class="close" href="http://localhost:3000/jobs/view/10"><img alt="No" src="/images/button_no.png" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

The generated html in production is:

```
<ul class="actions">
    <li><a rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="http://localhost:3000/jobs/delete/10"><img alt="Yes" src="/images/button_yes.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a class="close" href="http://localhost:3000/jobs/view/10"><img alt="No" src="/images/button_no.png" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, identical.

In development, this works fine. When you click on the "Yes" button, it works perfectly (POSTs to `/jobs/delete/:id`). In production though, suddenly it no longer works. Instead of POSTing, it now GETs the same URL with the following messages (with all the guff removed from the start of the lines for readability sake) in `production.log`

```
  INFO -- : Started GET "/jobs/delete/10" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-05 03:27:33 -0600
  INFO -- : Processing by JobsController#delete as HTML
  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"id"=>"10"}
 DEBUG -- : Geokit is using the domain: localhost
 DEBUG -- :   User Load (73.1ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 54 LIMIT 1
 DEBUG -- :   Job Load (77.2ms)  SELECT  `jobs`.* FROM `jobs` WHERE `jobs`.`id` = 10 LIMIT 1
  INFO -- :   Rendering jobs/delete.html.erb within layouts/application
  INFO -- :   Rendered jobs/delete.html.erb within layouts/application (0.6ms)
  INFO -- :   Rendered shared/_keywords.html.erb (0.1ms)
  INFO -- :   Rendered shared/_meta.html.erb (0.2ms)
  INFO -- :   Rendered shared/_styles.html.erb (0.7ms)
  INFO -- :   Rendered shared/_javascript.html.erb (0.8ms)
  INFO -- :   Rendered shared/_environment.html.erb (0.1ms)
  INFO -- :   Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 243ms (Views: 7.9ms | ActiveRecord: 150.3ms)
```

Where these are the first log messages after the `200 OK` message from the last request, so it's not just POSTing, failing and GETing after it fails.

Any help would be really appreciated, I'm completely stumped here.

EDIT:

Environment files, for funsies.

development.rb:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.eager_load = false
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true
  if Rails.root.join('tmp/caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=172800'
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.quiet = true
  config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
end
```

production.rb:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.eager_load_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

Comment: Does this work? `link_to (image_tag "/images/button_yes.png", alt: "Yes"), @job, method: :delete`

Comment: Nope, produces the exact same behavior and log results

Comment: That's very strange, there should be no difference in development and production. What's the generated HTML, both for development and production?

Comment: Believe me, I know. I edited my question to add it in for formatting's sake. This is a Rails 2 app that I've been upgrading to Rails 5, so there have been a lot of bizarre issues, but this is by far the most impenetrable I've encountered.

Comment: Ahh, going from 2 to 5 is a really big jump. There must be something in the environment files or even routes.rb that is messing this up. I must admit I'm stump on this issue, at least for now :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for trying though! Environment files are definitely my next stop. Cheers

Comment: @gabejbrenner did you figure this out? I've got more or less the exact same issue.