# Rails POST (patch) in development becomes GET in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, http

*The same situation as in [Rails link which POSTs in development GETs in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050608/rails-link-which-posts-in-development-gets-in-production) but there is no conclusion in that question, so I am trying as well:*

- Rails 5.2.3
- Ruby 2.6
- Running in Docker container
- Live app is on Ubuntu 16.04.6

I have the following in my view:

```
<%= link_to '&#10003;'.html_safe, item_path(item), method: :patch, :class=>"item__buy-btn" %>
```

It generates the following HTML:

```
<a class="item__buy-btn" rel="nofollow" data-method="patch" href="/items/32">✓</a>
```

This is in my item controller (I do not have a item#show):

```
def update
  item = Item.find(params[:id])
  item.update(bought: true)
  list = List.find(item.grocery_item_id)
  receipt = Receipt.find(list.receipts.last.id)
  receipt.close
  item.update(grocery_item_id: receipt.id, grocery_item_type: receipt.class.name)
  item.save
  redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
end
```

And this is my items related routes:

```
                items GET    /items(.:format)                                                                         items#index
                      POST   /items(.:format)                                                                         items#create
             new_item GET    /items/new(.:format)                                                                     items#new
            edit_item GET    /items/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                items#edit
                 item GET    /items/:id(.:format)                                                                     items#show
                      PATCH  /items/:id(.:format)                                                                     items#update
                      PUT    /items/:id(.:format)                                                                     items#update
                      DELETE /items/:id(.:format)                                                                     items#destroy
```

Clearly a POST:
[image: response in development]

Log says PATCH:

```
web_1              | Started PATCH "/items/33" for 172.21.0.1 at 2019- 05-05 19:29:31 +0000
web_1              | Cannot render console from 172.21.0.1! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
web_1              | Processing by ItemsController#update as HTML
web_1              |   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"KmPf0fEDEs6Y2gUmC6Su9fdeVOg51AwCUUWyQBq14Gz0Fs6IRJ5cmmQdUETMbE+IMRTTGcfQPQ86x0rNzDSRHg==", "id"=>"33"}
```

And then in PRODUCTION:

```
I, [2019-05-05T18:27:22.439552 #1]  INFO -- : [93c90971-1378-4e39-b6fb-8329dd46922e] Started GET "/" for 10.255.0.2 at 2019-05-05 18:27:22 +0000
I, [2019-05-05T18:27:22.440379 #1]  INFO -- : [93c90971-1378-4e39-b6fb-8329dd46922e] Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
I, [2019-05-05T18:27:22.441694 #1]  INFO -- : [93c90971-1378-4e39-b6fb-8329dd46922e]   Rendering home/index.html.erb within layouts/application
I, [2019-05-05T18:27:22.443279 #1]  INFO -- : [93c90971-1378-4e39-b6fb-8329dd46922e]   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.4ms)
I, [2019-05-05T18:27:22.444679 #1]  INFO -- : [93c90971-1378-4e39-b6fb-8329dd46922e] Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 3.0ms)
I, [2019-05-05T18:49:37.971732 #1]  INFO -- : [5f452d24-80c5-44dc-bd8a-cb2be0aa5f14] Started GET "/items/7" for 10.255.0.2 at 2019-05-05 18:49:37 +0000
F, [2019-05-05T18:49:37.973154 #1] FATAL -- : [5f452d24-80c5-44dc-bd8a-cb2be0aa5f14]
F, [2019-05-05T18:49:37.973209 #1] FATAL -- : [5f452d24-80c5-44dc-bd8a-cb2be0aa5f14] AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'show' could not be found for ItemsController):
F, [2019-05-05T18:49:37.973237 #1] FATAL -- : [5f452d24-80c5-44dc-bd8a-cb2be0aa5f14]
F, [2019-05-05T18:49:37.973274 #1] FATAL -- : [5f452d24-80c5-44dc-bd8a-cb2be0aa5f14] actionpack (5.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:129:in `process'
```

[image: response in production]

What could cause this behavior?
Is there any relevant information I am missing in this post?

EDIT:

**As per ser tadmans answer, it was apparently about the javascript.
It failed on precompile due to a '#' comment in one of the files.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usually happens because the Rails UJS JavaScript library failed to load and the data attributes it injects are ignored.

Check that the UJS library loaded. If you're using Sprockets, ensure that the `rails-ujs` "comment" line in `application.js` is present.

If you're running in `production` mode you need to ensure that your assets are properly compiled. This can be done with `rake assets:precompile` in the prouction deployment location for Rails 3 through 5.2.

Comment: (I might have downvoted this by accident, so it's nice if you could edit so I can change that)

Did `rake assets:precompile` in prod.
Got the following error `Uglifier::Error: Unexpected character '#'`

Removed some leftover comments from a coffeescript-file

That solved it.

Did you know this by experience, or is it somehting I shoul have figured out? And does this mean that my application will fail with no js?

Comment: This is something you need to do to properly "deploy" your application and tools like [Capistrano](https://capistranorb.com) do it for you automatically so many people don't know about it. Most deployment procedures discuss this step, but you need to go looking for them specifically: There's dozens of how-to guides that go over the details. Each environment has its own challenges, Docker especially.